# Modify Google Webmaster Robots.txt Code to disallow urls

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, web-crawler, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

I am getting some hreflang and redirect errors on ahrefs.com because of utm campaigns and popup links that have anchors set up as "#" or "#!". I want to add some code on my robots.txt file in order to prevent google from crawling these urls so that those errors disappear.

For example the urls I want to disallow crawling are:

*https://mywebsite.com/# 

https://mywebsite.com/#! 

https://mywebsite.com/about?utm_campaign=something*

**I tried this code but it isn't working:**

Disallow: /*#!

Disallow: /*utm_campaign

Answer (score 0):

Hash(#) is a sign of comment in robots.txt. Everything after # will be ignored in robots.txt

Also browsers and crawlers never send the part of the URL after the # to the server, so it's doesn't make sense to disallow it.